# UML Class Diagrams for 2D platformer Games?

Tags: c++, 2d, collision-detection, architecture, platformer

I have to develop a small arcade game in C++ for a college assignment using a 2D Game Engine my teacher coded. What would be the best way to make a UML class diagram for it? It's very basic stuff but I feel like I don't have the experience to make proper decisions on how to organize the classes. Seeing some examples of Class Diagrams from like Super Mario or any platformer would be perfect. For example would it be better to make a "Level" class where I load the bitmaps and handle the collisions, and then call this one in the main class, or just load my level stuff directly from my main class? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/45094/creating-a-uml-diagram

Comment: __ASK YOUR TEACHER FOR EXAMPLES__

Answer (score 0):

Software design is not an exact science. There's no *"the right way"* to do something as complex (and vague) as a 2D platformer game. **Didn't your teacher show any examples of UML?** You should think about this as any other software (or complex system). A nice UML diagram should answer these basic questions:

**What are your entities and what are the possible interactions between these entities?**

Try following a top-down approach - going from the abstract, high level elements towards the small details.

> "I don't have the experience to make proper decisions on how to
>   organize the classes."

I think this is the point of your homework. If you never try to implement what you've been taught, your education was just a waste of time and money.

Comment: Alright great, thanks for the reply. I've been reading up on UML diagrams and I came up with this: http://i.imgur.com/S35upEa.png